# On click of a hyperlink, need to pass the control to a method?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Please forgive me if you feel this is very basic question!

I have a label like below in the C# codebehind.

```
lblNewUser.Text= <a href="#">Click Here</a> +"to create a new user";
```

I have a separate method to create new user in the c#. I just want to navigate to the create user C# method when user click on the above link "Click Here"? How can i acheive this?

Comment: Look up how to use the asp.net `HyperLink` control.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find that knowing how to use the ASP.NET Hyperlink would help you.

Offical MSDN link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink(v=vs.110).aspx

Example: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_hyperlink.asp

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.